# Paste Special in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I am looking to **paste values** for the following piece of code. I tried using paste special a variety of ways but it does not let me specify both the file and what type of pasting I want to do.

To be clear, the code I am using works, but I would like to modify it so it pastes only values.

```
Workbooks.Open (path & file)
ActiveSheet.Paste (Workbooks(file).Sheets(5).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))
Workbooks(file).Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to show us the `PasteSpecial` commands that you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `PasteSpecial` associated with a worksheet object, use the one associated with the destination object:

```
Workbooks(file).Sheets(5).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

***OR***

You can work directly with the values and avoid using the clipboard (which you could be trying to use for other things while your macro is running):

```
Dim src as Range
Dim dest as Range

'Set src to where you had copied from
Set dest = Workbooks(file).Sheets(5).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
dest.value = src.value
```